# Basic Sample Spaces and Events Question

Tags: probability, permutations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the number of possible subsequences 2^n?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23513/why-is-the-number-of-possible-subsequences-2n)

I'm brushing up on my probability skills and the text asks the following question:

> For the sample space {A, B, C, D}, determine how many events are
>   possible.

I understand that an event is a subset of a sample space, so the question is essentially asking "how many subsets of {A, B, C, D} are there?"

Other than the brute force method of listing all the different subsets I can't figure out how to crack this question.

The book's answer is 16.

Help?